Computing $\int_0^1 \frac{x f(x)}{1+x^2} d x$, where $f(x)$ are the inverse of trigonometric functions.
Recently, I started to investigate the integrals involving the inverse of the six trigonometric functions $f(x)$:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x f(x)}{1+x^2} d x$$

by integration by parts as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x f(x)}{1+x^2} d x=&\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 f(x) d\left(\ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\left(\left[f(x) \ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 f^{\prime}(x) \ln \left(1+x^2\right) d x\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Let’s begin with the easier one
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan x}{1+x^2} d x=\frac{G}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2 } 
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x \arctan x}{1+x^2} d x 
= & \frac{1}{2}\left(\left\{\arctan x \ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} d x\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2+G\right) \\
= & \frac{G}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8} \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$ where G is the Catalan’s constant.

Then we proceed to $$\int_0^1 \frac{x \arcsin x}{1+x^2} d x $$ by  the Feynman’s trick.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x \arcsin x}{1+x^2} d x 
& = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left[\arcsin  x \ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} d x \right]\\&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(1+\sin ^2 \theta\right) d \theta\right], \quad \textrm{ where } x=\sin \theta\\&=  \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2-J(1)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
where $J(a)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(1+a \sin ^2 \theta\right) d \theta$. Differentiating $J(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
J^{\prime}(a) & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin ^2 \theta}{1+a \sin ^2 \theta} d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1+a \sin ^2 \theta-1}{1+a \sin ^2 \theta} d \theta \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2 a}-\frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+a \sin ^2 \theta} d \theta \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2 a}-\frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec ^2 \theta}{\sec ^2 \theta+a \tan ^2 \theta} d \theta \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2 a}-\frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d t}{(1+a) t^2+1} \quad t=\tan \theta \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2 a}-\frac{1}{a \sqrt{1+a}}\left[\tan ^{-1}(t \sqrt{1+a})\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a \sqrt{1+a}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating back yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
J(1) & =\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a \sqrt{1+a}}\right) d a \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2} \int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\left[\frac{1}{y^2-1}-\frac{1}{\left(y^2-1\right) y}\right] 2 y d y \\
& =\pi \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{y+1} d y \\
& =\pi[\ln (y+1)]_1^{\sqrt{2}}  \\
& =\pi \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{x \arcsin x}{1+x^2} d x=\frac{\pi}{4}[\ln 8-2 \ln (\sqrt{2}+1)]}
$$

Now it is simpler for $\int_0^1 \frac{x \arccos x}{1+x^2} d x$ by the identity $\arcsin x+\arccos x= \frac{\pi}{2}  $
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x \arccos x}{1+x^2} d x=&\int_0^1 \frac{x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin x\right)}{1+x^2} d x \\
= & \frac{\pi}{4}\left[\ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{x \arcsin x}{1+x^2} d x\\ =&\frac{\pi}{2} \ln \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Similarly, we can find
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 \frac{x \operatorname{arccot} x}{1+x^2} d x=\frac{1}{8}(\pi \ln 8-4 G)}
$$

I am stuck in $(1)$ the remaining two integrals which have simple and interesting complex values as their answer.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x \operatorname{arcsec} x}{1+x^2} d x&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left[\operatorname{arcsec} x \ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x \right]\\
&=-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x\\&=\frac{i}{2}\left(\operatorname{arcsinh^2}(1)\right) \cdots (1)
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 \frac{x \operatorname{arccsc} x d x}{1+x^2} d x = & \frac{1}{2}\left[\left[\operatorname{arccsc} x \ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x\right]\\
= & \frac{1}{4}\left[\pi \ln 2-2i\operatorname{arcsinh^2}(1))\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Questions:
How to prove that
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x=-i\left(\operatorname{arcsinh^2 }(1)\right)?
$$

Feynman trick works  with $\frac{\log \left(a^2 x^2+1\right)}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Thank your for your suggestion.  It works beautifully.

As Claude kindly suggested to use Feynman’s trick by the parametrised integral
$$
I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+a^2 x^2\right)}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x,
$$
differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =2 \int_0^1 \frac{a x}{\left(1+a^2 x^2\right) \sqrt{x^2-1}} d x \\
& =\int_0^1 \frac{a d x}{\left(1+a^2 x\right) \sqrt{x-1}} \\
& =2 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(a \sqrt{x-1})^2+a^2+1} d(a \sqrt{x-1}) \\
& =\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{a \sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right)\right]_0^1 \\
& =-\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} \arctan\left(\frac{i a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right) \\
& =-\frac{2 i}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} \operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating back gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =I(1)-I(0) \\
& =-2 i \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} \operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right) d a
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $a=\operatorname{sinh } \theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-2 i \int_0^{\operatorname{arcsinh } (1)} \theta d \theta \\
& =-i\left[\theta^2\right]_0^{\operatorname{arcsinh } (1)} \\
& =-i \operatorname{arcsinh^2}(1)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+a^2x^2\right)}{x \sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx$$
$$\frac{\partial  I(a)}{\partial a}=2a\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+a^2x^2)\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx$$
$$J(a)=\int_0^1\frac{x}{(1+a^2x^2)\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx=\frac{-i}{a\sqrt{a^2+1}}arctanh\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial  I(a)}{\partial a}=-2i\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}arctanh\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right)\right]$$
$$I(a)=-2i\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}arctanh\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right)\,da=-i \,arctanh\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right)^2+c$$
$$\boxed{I(0)=0\implies a=0, I(a)=0}$$
$$I(a)=-i \,arctanh\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\right)^2$$
$$I(1)=-i \,arctanh\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=-i\left(\operatorname{arcsinh^2 }(1)\right)$$
